# Axis label font styles not changing bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I have a figure `p`,

```py
p = bokeh.plotting.figure(
    width=300,
    height=250,
    x_axis_label='this is the x axis',
    y_axis_label="this is the y axis',
)
```

By default, the x and y axis label is in italic font style. I would like to change it to the normal style.

However, when I do:

```py
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_style = 'normal'
```

The y axis font style remains italic, and I get no error message.

What am I missing here?

I have also tried

```py
p.axis.axis_label_text_font_style = 'normal'
```

not specifying the axis, and  still there was no change.

Comment: I iust tried adding that line to the [iris.py example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/iris.py) and the axis font changed as expected. Please provide a complete example that reproduces what you are seeing, as well as more information (e.g. versions, how you are running)

Comment: The above worked for me as well. I tried on version `1.3.4`

Comment: p.axis.axis_label_text_font_style = 'normal' <-- this is working on 2.4.3